# No. of distinct subsequences of length 3 in an array of length n

Tags: arrays, algorithm, math, dynamic-programming, counting

How to calculate the number of distinct sub sequences of length `3` (or in general of length `k < n`) in an array of length `n`?

**Note:** Two sub sequences are considered different if the order of elements in them are different.

Ex: Suppose the array `A = [1, 2, 1, 1]`, then the answer should be `3` because there are only three distinct subsequences of length `3` as shown below:

```
[1, 1, 1]
[1, 2, 1]
[2, 1, 1]
```

Size of the array `n <= 10^5`, each element in the array `A_i <= n`.

My approach:

I figured the brute force approach, i.e., to take tuples of length `3` and insert it into a map. But this is neither space/time efficient.

**Edit**: This was an interview question and it said that **for k = 3** the expected time and space complexity is `O(n)`.

Comment: Shouldn't you have 1, 1, 2 as part of the solution as well?

Comment: @kishore By definition, elements of the subsequence of an array needs to occur in the same order as the original array. Hence, we cannot have `1, 1, 2`.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

As is often the case with interview problems, there's a dynamic programming solution. Let `T(m, k)` be the number of distinct length-`k` subsequences of the first `m` elements. Then assuming one-based indexing on the input `A`, we have a 2D recurrence

```
T(m, 0) = 1
T(m, k) = T(m-1, k) + T(m-1, k-1) -
          ^^^^^^^^^   ^^^^^^^^^^^
     A_m not chosen   A_m chosen

            { T(i-1, k-1), if i < m is the maximum index where A_i = A_m
            { 0,           if no such index exists
```

The subtracted term ensures that we don't count duplicates; see https://stackoverflow.com/a/5152203/2144669 for more explanation.

The running time (with a hash map to maintain the rightmost occurrence so far of each symbol seen) is `O(k n)`, which is `O(n)` for `k = 3`.

Answer (score 5):

Here's a slightly different take. We can think of the number of ways an element, `m`, can be `k`th in the subsequence as the sum of all the ways the previous occurence of any element (including `m`) can be `(k-1)`th. As we move right, however, the only update needed is for `m`; the other sums stay constant.

For example,

```
// We want to avoid counting [1,1,1], [1,2,1], etc. twice
[1, 2, 1, 1, 1]
```

(display the array vertically for convenience)

```
            <-  k  ->
[1,  ->  1: [1, 0, 0]
 2,  ->  2: [1, 1, 0]
 1,  ->  1: [1, 2, 1]
 1,  ->  1: [1, 2, 3]
 1]  ->  1: [1, 2, 3]
```

Now if we added another element, say 3,

```
...
 3]  ->  3: [1, 2, 3]

 // 1 means there is one way
 // the element, 3, can be first

 // 2 means there are 2 ways
 // 3 can be second: sum distinct
 // column k[0] = 1 + 1 = 2

 // 3 means there are 3 ways
 // 3 can be third: sum distinct
 // column k[1] = 2 + 1 = 3
```

Sum distinct `k[2]` column:

```
0 + 3 + 3 = 6 subsequences

[1,2,1], [2,1,1], [1,1,1]
[1,1,3], [2,1,3], [3,2,1]
```

The sum-distinct for each column can be updated in `O(1)` per iteration. The `k` sums for the current element (we update a single list of those for each element), take `O(k)`, which in our case is `O(1)`.

JavaScript code:

```js
function f(A, k){
  A.unshift(null);
  
  let sumDistinct = new Array(k + 1).fill(0);
  let hash = {};

  sumDistinct[0] = 1;

  for (let i=1; i<A.length; i++){
    let newElement;
    
    if (!hash[A[i]]){
      hash[A[i]] = new Array(k + 1).fill(0);
      newElement = true;
    }
    
    let prev = hash[A[i]].slice();

    // The number of ways an element, m, can be k'th
    // in the subsequence is the sum of all the ways
    // the previous occurence of any element
    // (including m) can be (k-1)'th
    for (let j=1; j<=k && j<=i; j++)
      hash[A[i]][j] = sumDistinct[j - 1];

    for (let j=2; j<=k && j<=i; j++)
      sumDistinct[j] = sumDistinct[j] - prev[j] + hash[A[i]][j];

    if (newElement)
      sumDistinct[1] += 1;

    console.log(JSON.stringify([A[i], hash[A[i]], sumDistinct]))
  }

  return sumDistinct[k];
}

var arr = [1, 2, 1, 1, 1, 3, 2, 1];

console.log(f(arr, 3));
```